# What is the recommended way of deploying a Java EE application in IIS?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, tomcat, java, iis-8

I was given the task of deploying a Java EJB application in Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8.

The application was previously deployed to *Glassfish 4* on Jelastic. After checking the requirements, I decided that *Apache TomEE Plus* version 7.1 would be a fit replacement. TomEE is essentially a Java Enterprise Edition version of Tomcat.

The problem is I can't figure out what is the canonical way to serve such an application with IIS.

The options I came across are these:

- [the ISAPI redirector](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html) <sup>[(2)](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/tomcat-iis-howto.html) [(3)](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/iis.html)</sup> (aka "jakarta"), part of Tomcat
- [the HttpPlatformHandler](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-release-of-the-httpplatformhandler-module-for-iis-8/) <sup>[(2)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/httpplatformhandler/httpplatformhandler-configuration-reference)</sup>, by Microsoft
- [the Web Farm Framework](https://jstoup.wordpress.com/tag/integrate-glassfish-and-iis/) <sub>(linked instructions are for Glassfish, but can be applied to Tomcat)</sub>
- [Application Request Routing](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/11/05/how-to-configure-iis-arr-application-request-routing-to-redirect-to-tomcat/)
- a third party [IIS to Tomcat Connector](http://tomcatiis.riaforge.org/).

**Which of these would be recommended for a production server**?

I already tried the ISAPI redirector (related question: *https://serverfault.com/q/952151/300053*) and also the HttpPlatformHandler, which simply didn't work - all requests take forever to complete.

Thanks.

Comment: Different perspectives of your team can lead to different choices. Microsoft would only support you if you use HttpPlatformHandler or ARR.

Comment: Why don't you just use TomEE on Jelastic and save yourself time?

Comment: @Damien-Layershift I was hired by a hosting company to setup this specific application on their bare metal server.